# Hacer transacción en sql server con procedimiento almacenado en visual basic (Visual Studio)?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedure, visual-studio-2013, transacciones

bueno necesito hacer una transaccion en vb de visual studio 2013 con un procedimiento almacenado de sql server 2014. Sé como ejecutar procedimientos almacenados normales donde se utiliza un delete, insert o select.. pero no de transaccion y que me informe, por ejemplo, si se ha podido realizar la transaccion (commit) o si no se ha podido realizar (Rollback). Por favor algun consejo, todo es bienvenido! muchas gracias. Saludos.

Para llamar al procedimiento lo hago desde una clase en donde creo una función que se encargue específicamente de dicha tarea (ejecutar el procedimiento creado en sql). Posteriormente a su coneccion con una funcion FnConectado() que declare en otra clase.

```
Public Function FnMostrarClientes() As DataTable
    Try
        FnConectado()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("mostrar_clientes")
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Connection = cnn

        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            Return dt
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        FnDesconectado()
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Buenas Manuel, añade todo el código que puedas con las pruebas que has hecho. ¿Cómo llamas el procedimiento?

Comment: Hola Manuel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. A parte de lo que dice @Marc, mira [ask] para mejorar tu pregutna. Un saludo

Comment: Usar transacciones es .Net es muy sencillo. [En la página de MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) tienes un ejemplo muy claro. Échale un vistazo y si tienes problemas vuelve y pregunta algo mas concreto. Un saludo

Comment: Que tal @Manuel Pereyra, las transacciones las puedes hacer desde tu Stored Procedure, pero para poder ayudar necesito que me digas que operaciones quieres hacer exactamente con el Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Tambien podrias utilizar [SqlTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx) con lo cual tu codigo quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
 Public Function FnMostrarClientes() As DataTable
    Dim transaccion As SqlTransaction
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    Try
        Using cnn
            FnConectado()
            transaccion = cnn.BeginTransaction

            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.Transaction = transaccion
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "mostrar_clientes"

            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim dt As DataTable

            da.Fill(dt)

            transaccion.Commit()

            Return dt
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        transaccion.Rollback()
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        FnDesconectado()
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que quieres realizar lo puedes hacer facilmente con [Adjunto link, TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.110).aspx)
Es muy simple de usar, te dejo un ejemplo.

```
Public Function FnMostrarClientes() As DataTable
Try
   Using scope As New TransactionScope()
    FnConectado()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("mostrar_clientes")
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Connection = cnn

    If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
        Return dt
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
  scope.Complete()
  End Using
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Return Nothing
Finally
    FnDesconectado()
End Try
```

End Function